# how to check whether ALL elements in a Pandas series are equal to a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

For a given series, e.g.

```
s = pd.Series([0,0,0])
```

I would like to check whether ALL elements in this series are equal to a specific value (we can use 0 in this example) and return TRUE if that is the case, and FALSE  otherwise.

is there a handy way to do those in Pandas/numpy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the following syntax:

```
s = pd.Series([0,0,0])

print(s.eq(0).all())
True
```

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do the same would be:

```
print((s==0).all())
```